# Azure Storage Blob (v12) Python API: Retry while acquiring lease

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am using Python API for Azure Storage v12.x ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/storage-blob-readme?view=azure-python)). I am trying to acquire lease for a blob using the following code:

```
credentials = ...
blob_client = BlobClient(account_url=ACCOUNT_URL, container_name=CONTAINER_NAME, blob_name=BLOB_NAME, credential=credentials)
lease_id_str = str(uuid.uuid4())
lease = blob_client.acquire_lease(lease_duration=60, lease_id=lease_id_str)
```

Now, I want to retry if the lease is not available. The question is **"How should I acquire lease with retry?"**

Following are the few things I have tried:

1.[This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/storage-blob-readme?view=azure-python#retry-policy-configuration) talks about properties `retry_connect`, `retry_read`, `retry_status`. Adding those as additional argument to the above code didn't help.

2.Following [this test case](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/fc38db1cea8e6b7f22b29f3218c7bcf0f24668ca/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/tests/test_retry.py), I have tried following:

```
from azure.storage.blob import ExponentialRetry

retry = ExponentialRetry(initial_backoff=1, increment_base=3, retry_total=3)
lease = BlobLeaseClient(blob_client, lease_id=lease_id_str, retry_policy=retry)
```

It returned the following:

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'retry_policy'

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason you're getting this error is because you're trying to pass unsupported `retry_policy` argument to `BlobLeaseClient`.

If you look at the test case link code you shared, there retry policy is passed to `BlobServiceClient` object. Can you try using that? Something like:

```
retry = ExponentialRetry(initial_backoff=1, increment_base=3, retry_total=3)
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=ACCOUNT_URL, credential=credentials, retry_policy=retry)
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=CONTAINER_NAME, blob=BLOB_NAME)
lease = BlobLeaseClient(blob_client, lease_id=lease_id_str)
```

Or try something like the following. Here, the retry policy is passed when creating an instance of `BlobClient`.

```
credentials = ...
retry = ExponentialRetry(initial_backoff=1, increment_base=3, retry_total=3)
blob_client = BlobClient(account_url=ACCOUNT_URL, container_name=CONTAINER_NAME, blob_name=BLOB_NAME, credential=credentials, retry_policy=retry)
lease = BlobLeaseClient(blob_client, lease_id=lease_id_str)
```

Comment: None of the approaches work. :-(  Also, the arguments for `get_blob_client` are `container` and `blob` (not `container_name` and `blob_name`)

Comment: Still getting the same error? I tried this with uploading a blob and didn't get any errors.

Comment: No Errors. But, based on the logs, I don't see any retry.

Comment: Oh, that's a different thing all together. Please note that not all exceptions are retryable by default (e.g. none of the 400 errors will be retryable). What's the HTTP status code you're getting back?